# App\Tasks::first()->projects; in artisan tinker returns null, no matter what :(

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

The following code in tinker returns a null value while it should return the project to which the first task is linked.

```
App\Task::first()->projects;
```

Already tried renaming the method names, column names in migrations, tried exiting tinker and logging back in

Project Migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Task Migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->boolean('completed')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Project.php

```
use App\Task;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','description'];

    public function tasks(){
      return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
}
```

Task.php

```
use App\Project;

class Task extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'completed'
  ];
  public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
  }
}
```

If anyone could just review this piece of code and let me know where I have made any conventional\idiotic mistakes (since Im new to route model binding) it would be of great help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A task belongs to a project, so rename projects to project as it is singular. If you keep projects then provide the column name as second parameter:

```
public function projects(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'project_id');
}

// I suggest this
public function project(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

- Your column types are different, for the id of the project you use Big Integer and for the reference you use Integer, so this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('project_id');
```

should be this:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');

// also good to make the relationship on the Database level:

$table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
```